# Checking for a specific URL regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to check for a specific URL pattern using regex and not sure what would be the approach but I think it should not be too complex for this case and therefore regex would be the preferred solution. I just need to check that the exact strings `#`, `shares` and `assets` are in the appropriate slots, for example:
`http://some-domain.com/#/shares/a454-rte3-445f-4543/assets`

Everything in the URL can be variable (protocol, domain, port, share id) except the exact strings I'm looking for and the slots (slash positions) at which they appear.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
/^https?:\/\/some-domain\.com\/#\/shares\/[^/]+\/assets/i
```

[image]

```js
let url = `http://some-domain.com/#/shares/a454-rte3-445f-4543/assets`

let matched = /^https?:\/\/some-domain\.com\/#\/shares\/[^/]+\/assets/i.test(url)

console.log(matched)
```

Comment: he also wants `/https?/`

Comment: @MaximMazurok just add s? it will be enough, and these sorts of requirements should go with question itself

Comment: I know, see my answer and comments, the question is not clear...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion folks, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to avoid regex and do it this way instead.

```
const urlParts = window.location.href.split('/');
if (urlParts[3] === '#' && urlParts[4] === 'shares' && urlParts[6] === 'assets') {
 // code goes here...
}
```